# Error: keyboard key - Cancel desktop command on Windows 10 (How to disable desktop view)

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I accidentally pressed a keyboard key and since then I can't work in several applications unless I always press Win+D (desktop view). That's when a small black window appeared in the bottom left that said "Desktop".

So, for example, if I want to work in Excel and Word and TotalCmd, I click on their icons in vain, because nothing happens.

To work with each of them, I have to press Win+D quite often.

How do I cancel this error? How to disable desktop view?

Comment: Do you remember which keyboard key you pushed? Have you rebooted?

Comment: I don't remember. I just remember that small black window appeared in the bottom left that said "Desktop".

Comment: Have you rebooted since then?

Comment: not yet. I have a download running. I will restart the laptop in about 2 hours. I hope this will fix the problem. But I wanted to know if there is another solution. (I will write again after restart)

Comment: yes, I just RESTART the laptop, and the error was fix. So, the restart is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This link covers various ways to check and adjust your Desktop View settings:
https://www.howtogeek.com/676271/how-to-quickly-show-your-desktop-on-windows-10/

Make sure that "Peek at Desktop" is off.

> Windows 10 includes a second way of looking at the desktop quickly
> called Aero Peek. To use it, first find the tiny “Show Desktop” button
> on the far-right side of the taskbar. It looks like this:
>
> [image: Windows 10 Desktop View button]
>
> Right-click on the “Show Desktop” button and a tiny menu will pop up.
>
> This menu has two options. The first, “Show desktop,” is an action. If
> you click on it, you will see the Desktop just as if you had
> left-clicked on the button. The second option, named “Peek At
> Desktop,” is a toggle setting. If you click it, a checkmark will
> appear to its left.
>
> [image: Peek at Desktop Option]

**Note** : In the poster's case, a reboot fixed the problem.

Comment: yes, I just RESTART the laptop, and the error was fix. So, the restart is also a solution.